# AngularJS : multiple directives in a single page not receiving mouse events

Tags: angularjs, events, d3.js, scope, directive

I have a series of rather complex D3 directives that are all embedded in a single view in angular. Originally each one lived on a separate view (with lots of other content) and in that context each performs exactly as intended. It was decided that we should aggregate these data interactive components into a single view location for easier access, and since each directive is an isolate scope returning a link function that contains all the logic with no reference to the parent scope of the view controller, I assumed it would be as easy as this:

```
<eaa-gauge-data-interactive-recharge></eaa-gauge-data-interactive-recharge>
<eaa-gauge-data-interactive-wells></eaa-gauge-data-interactive-wells>
<eaa-gauge-data-interactive-springs></eaa-gauge-data-interactive-springs>
```

However, when I do that only the first directive seems to be receiving all the mouse events (even when it is hidden and off screen while the others are visible and on screen).

The directive definition object is essentially identical in each:

```
var directiveDefinitionObject = {
  compile: false,
  controller: false,
  controllerAs: false,
  link: false,
  priority: 0,
  require: false,
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  template: false,
  templateUrl: false,
  terminal: false,
  transclude: false,
  type: false
};
```

Since there is no parent controller reference, an isolate scope is defined, and the directives are never onscreen at the same time (and so there is no 'invisible' overlapping of the interactive portions) I do not understand why only the first operates correctly.

For clarity, here is one of the link functions (they are roughly equivalent in structure). And also I know I am missing some best practices here (like not using $http.get to load my external resources - I'm working on cleaning that stuff up).

```
directiveDefinitionObject.link = function postLink (scope, element) {

  // VARS.
  var container = $('#interactive');
  var containerWidth = container.width();

  var width = containerWidth;
  var height = width * 0.75;

  var vizMargin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0};
  var vizWidth = width - vizMargin.left - vizMargin.right;
  var vizHeight = height - vizMargin.top - vizMargin.bottom;

  var dataDisplayWidth = vizWidth * 0.4;
  var dataDisplayHeight = vizHeight * 0.4;

  var mapWidth = vizWidth;
  var mapHeight = vizHeight * 0.35;

  var graphWidth = vizWidth;
  var graphHeight = vizHeight * 0.45;
  var graphLeftOffset = vizWidth * 0.05;
  var graphWidthOffset = 0.98;

  var boundariesSource = '../../data/geojson/eaa-aquifer-zones-2014.geo.json';
  var dataSource = '../../data/recharge-annualAvg-byDate2.csv';
  var ingestedData = {};

  var markerRadius = 5;
  var mapLabels = [];
  var mapLabelsLength = mapLabels.length;

  var legendBoxDimensions = 20;
  var legendVertSpacingFactor = 1;
  var legendVertOffset = legendBoxDimensions * 0.8;

  var color = d3.scale.category10().domain(['Barton Springs', 'Comal Springs', 'Hueco Springs', 'J17', 'J27', 'Las Moras Springs', 'Leona Springs', 'San Antonio Springs', 'San Marcos Springs', 'San Pedro Springs']);
  var dataKey = d3.scale.ordinal();
  var parseDate = d3.time.format('%Y');

  var x = d3.time.scale().range([graphLeftOffset, graphWidth*graphWidthOffset]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([graphHeight-50, 50]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').ticks(20);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left').ticks(10);

  var xPosRange = [];
  var xNumericRange = 0;
  var dateRange = [];
  var xMinDate = 0;
  var xMaxDate = 0;
  var dateDelta = 0;
  var posYear = 0;

  var dataRange = [];
  var dataRangeMax = {};
  var dataRangeMin = {};
  var oldDataRange = {};
  var newDataMax = 100;
  var newDataMin = 0;
  var newDataRange = newDataMax - newDataMin;
  var newValue = {};
  var decimalValue = {};

  var criticalPeriodStage04 = 'rgba(150,0,0,1)';
  var criticalPeriodStage03 = 'rgba(150,0,0,1)';
  var criticalPeriodStage02 = 'rgba(150,100,0,1)';
  var criticalPeriodStage01 = 'rgba(0,0,150,1)';

  // METHODS.
  Array.prototype.max = function() {
    var max = this[0];
    var len = this.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) if (this[i] > max) max = this[i];
    return max;
  };

  Array.prototype.min = function() {
    var min = this[0];
    var len = this.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) if (this[i] < min) min = this[i];
    return min;
  };

  d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
  };

  d3.selection.prototype.moveToBack = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild;
      if (firstChild) {
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild);
      }
    });
  };

  var roundDecimals = function (value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
  };

  var defineInteractionRange = function () {
    xPosRange = [graphLeftOffset, graphWidth*graphWidthOffset];
    xNumericRange = xPosRange[1] - xPosRange[0];
    xMinDate = dateRange.min();
    xMaxDate = dateRange.max();
    dateDelta = xMaxDate - xMinDate;
    posYear = xNumericRange / dateDelta;
    setDisplayDate(xMaxDate);
  };

  var defineDataRange = function () {
    dataRangeMin = dataRange.min();
    dataRangeMax = dataRange.max();
    oldDataRange = dataRangeMax - dataRangeMin;
  };

  var setDataValuePercent = function (dataValue) {
    if (dataValue === 0) {
      newValue = newDataMin;
    } else {
      newValue = (((dataValue - dataRangeMin) * newDataRange) / oldDataRange) + newDataMin;
    }

    decimalValue = roundDecimals((newValue / 100), 2);
  };

  var setMapFillValue = function () {
    // simple approach - change opacity based on values.
    d3.selectAll('.Recharge.Zone').transition().style('fill', 'rgba(113,178,201,' + decimalValue + ')').duration(100);
  };

  var updateMapDisplay = function (dataValue) {
    setDataValuePercent(dataValue);
    setMapFillValue();      
  };

  var setDisplayDate = function (targetDate) {
    d3.select('.year-display').text(Math.round(targetDate));
  };

  var setDisplayData = function (targetIndex) {        
    var dataSet = ingestedData[targetIndex];        
    var vals = Object.keys(dataSet).map(function (key) {
      return dataSet[key];
    });
    // Loop through all elements with class legend-item under the legend element.
    var dataLabelArray = d3.select('.legend').selectAll('.legend-item').selectAll('text');
    // console.log(dataLabelArray[0][1]); // THIS ONE!!!
    // Need to populate each legend-item text value with the appropriate val index string (remember to skip 0 which is the Date value).
    for (var j=0; j < dataLabelArray.length; j++) {
      var displayValue = '';
      var dataIndexOffset = j + 1;
      d3.select(dataLabelArray[j][1]).text( function() {
        var thisValue = vals[dataIndexOffset].toString();

        if (thisValue == 'NaN') {
          displayValue = 'No Data';
        } else {
          displayValue = thisValue;
        }

        updateMapDisplay(displayValue);
        return displayValue;
      });
    }
  };

  var updateIndicatorLine = function (xPos) {
    var indicatorLine = d3.select('.indicator-line');
    var gBounds = d3.select('.graph-bounds');
    var y1Pos = gBounds[0][0].clientHeight * 0.15;
    var y2Pos = gBounds[0][0].clientHeight * 0.845;

    indicatorLine.attr('x1', xPos).attr('y1', y1Pos).attr('x2', xPos).attr('y2', y2Pos);
  };

  var deriveDate = function (xPos) {
    var indicatorLine = d3.select('.indicator-line');

    if (xPos < xPosRange[0]) {
      setDisplayDate(xMinDate);
      indicatorLine.style('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else if (xPos > xPosRange[1]) { 
      setDisplayDate(xMaxDate);
      indicatorLine.style('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
      var normalizedX = xPos - xPosRange[0];
      var yearIndex = normalizedX / posYear;
      var currentDate = xMinDate + yearIndex;
      setDisplayDate(currentDate);
      setDisplayData(Math.round(yearIndex));
      indicatorLine.style('visibility', 'visible');
      updateIndicatorLine(xPos);
    }
  };

  var mouseOverGraph = function (event) {
    var position = d3.mouse(this);
    deriveDate(position[0]);
  };

  var onTargetClick = function (target) {
    console.log(target.properties.Name);
  };

  // VIZ - BASE.
  var el = element[0];
  var viz = d3.select(el).append('div').attr('class', 'viz').attr('width', vizWidth).attr('height', vizHeight);
  viz.on('mousemove', mouseOverGraph);
  viz.append('text').attr('class','year-display').text('');

  var dataDisplay = viz.append('div').attr('class','data-display');

  var geoBounds = viz.append('svg').attr('class', 'geo-bounds recharge')
    .attr('width', mapWidth)
    .attr('height', mapHeight);

  var graphBounds = viz.append('svg').attr('class', 'graph-bounds')
    .attr('width', graphWidth)
    .attr('height', graphHeight);

  // interpolate options: basis, basis-open, basis-closed, linear, step, step-before, step-after, bundle, cardinal, cardinal-open, cardinal-closed, monotone;
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.gindex); })
    .defined(function (d) { return d.gindex; });

  // MAP.
  d3.json(boundariesSource, function (error, boundariesData) {
    if (error) {
      return console.error(error);
    }
    var scale = mapHeight * 30; // geojson display.
    var offset = [mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2];
    var center = d3.geo.centroid(boundariesData);
    // Valid projection types: azimuthalEqualArea, azimuthalEquidistant, conicEqualArea, conicConformal, conicEquidistant, equirectangular, gnomonic, mercator, orthographic, stereographic, 
    // Note: albersUsa() and transverseMercator() require additional configs.
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(scale).center(center).translate(offset);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    var geoBoundaries = geoBounds.selectAll('g').data(boundariesData.features).enter().append('g');
    geoBoundaries.append('path').attr('d', path).attr('class', function (d) { return 'subunit ' + d.properties.Name; }).attr('stroke', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)').on('click', onTargetClick);
  });

  // CHART.
  d3.csv(dataSource, function (error, data) {

    data.forEach(function (d) {
      dateRange.push(parseInt(d.Date));
      d.Date = parseDate.parse(d.Date);  
      dataRange.push(parseFloat(d['Total Recharge']));        
      d['Total Recharge'] = +d['Total Recharge'];
    });

    ingestedData = data;

    dataKey.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== 'Date'; }));

    var gauges = dataKey.domain().map(function (name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function (d) {
          return { date: d.Date, gindex: +d[name] };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.Date; }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(gauges, function (c) { return d3.min(c.values, function (v) { return v.gindex; }); }),
      d3.max(gauges, function (c) { return d3.max(c.values, function (v) { return v.gindex; }); })
    ]);

    graphBounds.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('id', 'xAxis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (graphHeight - 50) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

    graphBounds.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .attr('id', 'yAxis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + graphLeftOffset + ',0)')
      .call(yAxis)
      .append('text')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
      .attr('x', -50)
      .attr('dy', '1em')
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .text('thousands of acre-feet');

    var gauge = graphBounds.selectAll('.gauge')
      .data(gauges)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'gauge-data');

    gauge.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', function (d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style('stroke', function (d) { return color(d.name); })
      .attr('id', function (d) { return d.name; });

    // Filter data points by gauge.
    var filtered = gauge.filter(function (d) {
        // console.log(d.name);
        // return d.name == 'J27';
        // return d.values.gindex !== NaN;
        // return d.name === 'Barton Springs' || 'Comal Springs' || 'Hueco Springs' || 'J17' || 'J27' || 'Las Moras Springs' || 'Leona Springs' || 'San Antonio Springs' || 'San Marcos Springs' || 'San Pedro Springs';
      })
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(function (d) { return d.values; })
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr({ cx: function (d) { return x(d.date); }, cy: function (d) { return y(d.gindex); }, r: 2 })
      .style('fill', '#555');

    var indicatorLine = graphBounds.append('line').attr('x1', 0).attr('y1', 0).attr('x2', 0).attr('y2', 0).attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('stroke', 'rgba(50,50,50,0.9)').attr('class', 'indicator-line');

    // LEGEND.
    var legend = dataDisplay.append('div').attr('class','legend legend-recharge').attr('transform', 'translate(-180,30)');
    var legendItem = legend.selectAll('.svg').data(gauges).enter().append('svg').attr('class', 'legend-item');

    var box = legendItem.append('rect')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', function (d, i) { return i * legendVertSpacingFactor; })
      .attr('width', legendBoxDimensions)
      .attr('height', legendBoxDimensions)
      .attr('class', 'legend-box')
      .style('fill', function (d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style('stroke', '#000');

    var label = legendItem.append('text')
      .attr('x', 30)
      .attr('y', function (d, i) { return (i * legendVertSpacingFactor) + legendVertOffset; })
      .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    var dataValue = legendItem.append('text')
      .attr('x', 250)
      .attr('y', function (d, i) { return (i * legendVertSpacingFactor) + legendVertOffset; })
      .text('')
      .attr('class', 'data-value');

    // NOTE.
    var notes = viz.append('div').attr('class','graph-notes')
      .append('text')          
      .text('Note: Any gaps in the data lines represent gaps in the collected data for that time period.');          

    defineInteractionRange();
    defineDataRange();
  });     
};
```

Any of them can be first in the page and if so will operate as intended. This seems to be a case where the first directive is intercepting all the events, but I do not understand why given the isolate scopes and lack of any external controller references in the link function.

There is also a Leaflet directive in the same view and it DOES receive all its events correctly (it is first in the view) and the immediate following directive will be the one that works, so the event interception does not seem to be a global problem per say (or perhaps the Leaflet directive has better scoping and event handling - I did not write that one).

I must be missing something either very fundamental or very obscure. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? So if you console.log in the mouseOver function, you get nothing?

Comment: I am using angular 1.2.17. But THANK YOU! I added in a console log to mouseOverGraph() and they are in fact still receiving the mouseover events,so something else in my directives is off. Using that same approach I have traced that events are firing all the way up the chain (mouseOverGraph > deriveDate > updateIndicatorLine).

Comment: It seems only the elements classed as 'indicator-line' and 'year-display' are not doing their part (in the directives that aren't updating their view). This again seems to me like it should be handled by the isolate scope, but I don't really know how to start debugging this. I could just give them each unique class names per directive but I was working towards making these directives (ultimately) externally configurable as a reusable component so that would not help me towards that end.

Comment: Typically in cases like this it just means that the first item is gobbling up all the mouse events  rather than letting them propagate when they are not of interest.  Look for places where you may have stopPropagation() or maybe preventDefault()

Comment: OK! This helped a ton. After testing, it looks like the first directive on the view is receiving all the events. Apparently I need to use a namespace or something within my directive to ensure it references only its instance of the indicator-line and the date.

That said, I am not quite clear on how to use the namespace appropriately within a directive to reference itself.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you isolated the issue and created a fiddle

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but you could create a UUID in each link function, then name the classes like indicator-line-(some_uuid). Can use regex CSS selectors if needed to access them. I don't think thats needed though, should work without doing that.

Comment: Oh, I think its in you updateIndicatorLine function. The d3.select('.indicator-line') call will find *all* the elements on the page. I think you want just the ones in this chart

Comment: So you need to reference element[0] first, then select all .indicator-line

Comment: Ahh, yup. Getting the reference to the element[0] first did the trick. Same for the year-display. Fantastic!! Thanks a ton reptilicus! Now how can I select your comment as the answer? (I still have not figured out the SO usage properly =/)

Comment: OK, I finally RTFM'd - reptilicus could you submit that as an answer so I can accept? because that was the culprit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I think its in you `updateIndicatorLine` function. The `d3.select('.indicator-line')` call will find all the elements on the page. I think you want just the ones in this chart. So you need to reference `element[0]` first, then select all `.indicator-line`.